# SQL - Using Variable as Column Name with count(@variable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I need to determine the duplicates within a large number of different columns. Rather than typing out each column name, I tried to use the following code. This is slightly more efficient because I only need to type the column name once. However, I get this error:

Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Each `GROUP BY` expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

```
declare @TheCount varchar(100)
set @TheCount = 'Column_1'
select @TheCount, count(@TheCount) as LineCount
from staging
group by @TheCount
having count(@TheCount) > 1
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: [What and Why "this Error":](http://www.sqlerror.sqlserver-training.com/tag/each-group-by-expression-must-contain-at-least-one-column-that-is-not-an-outer-reference/)

Comment: You will have to look at using dynamic sql if you want to use variables as the column names. See [the curse and blessing of dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script will be useful (assuming that is Sql Server):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
a int
)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(4)

declare @TheCount varchar(100)
set @TheCount = 'a'

EXEC('select ' + @TheCount + ', count(' + @TheCount + ') as LineCount
      from test
      group by ' + @TheCount + '
      having count(' + @TheCount + ') > 1
      order by 2 desc')
```

You can try this example **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82ba5/2)**.

Note: this is a little example of "Dynamic Sql Execution", here a [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/28/sql-server-executing-dynamic-sql-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-4-query-programming-objects-for-sql-server-2012/) for a little explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @column_list varchar(4000) = 'column_name1,column_name2,column_name3,etc';

DECLARE @sql = '
  WITH dups AS (
    SELECT 
      *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY '+@column_list'+)) AS n
    FROM table_name
  SELECT * FROM dups WHERE n > 1';

EXEC @sql;
```